# Change contextily basemap size

Tags: python, geopandas, contextily

I am creating a program that maps out postal codes of my choosing and then applies a colormap based on some conditions. The issue I am running into is that I would like the resulting image to always be specific dimensions. I am using data from https://www.suche-postleitzahl.org/downloads.

Currently, I am plotting my postal codes from a geodataframe:

```py
import geopandas as gdp
import contextily as ctx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

postal_codes = [10117, 10178, 10179]
germany_df = gpd.read_file('./plz-gebiete.shp')
plot_df = germany_df.query('plz == @postal_codes')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plot_df.plot(ax=ax)
```

and I am adding a basemap using contextily like so:

```py
ctx.add_basemap(ax, source=ctx.providers.OpenStreetMap.Mapnik)
```

I tried

```py
plt.subplots(figsize=(14,11)
```

and also

```py
plot_df.plot(ax=ax, figsize=(14,11))
```

These increase the size of the resulting postal code plot, but not my basemap.

The behavior I would like is a resizing of the basemap, but I can't find any way to do this in the contextily documentation.

Comment: Please share your code.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Check this intro-guide https://contextily.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro_guide.html